# Быстрая установка в Android Studio ничего не устанавливает

Tags: android-studio

После установки Android Studio 2.1 обнаружил одну интересную "фичу" - быструю установку приложений, которая вносит только нужные изменения и очень быстро устанавливает приложение. При работе с разметкой она мне очень нравилась и действительно сэкономила много времени (очень удобно: изменил -> запустил -> посмотрел и это меньше, чем за 10 секунд!), но вот я добрался до Java кода..... Иногда, когда я делаю изменения в коде и запускаю установку, эта "быстрая установка" делает вид, что что-то устанавливает и тихо, пока я не вижу (а я же, умный, отключил уведомление...), пишет в консоль :

```
05/30 01:25:01: Launching app
No changes.
```

Соответсвенно, ничего не устанавливается, а когда я это замечаю - вспоминая нехорошими словами эту "фичу", иду заново 20 раз пошагово делать изменения кода и перезапускать приложение, пытаясь вычислить ошибку.

Так вот, как сделать, чтобы эта "быстарая установка" ВСЕГДА переустанавливала приложение, а не просто писала, что не нашла изменений?

Comment: Не удаляйте вопросы, ответы на кои вы не смогли найти удовлетворяющим вас способом

Comment: Никак. В каких случаях и на каких API функция Instant run работает подробно описано [здесь](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run). Если вам не нравится ее работа просто отключите в настройках

Comment: @pavlofff, добавьте в ответ. Разве что можете добавить, что, если в эмуляторе\телефоне свернуть приложение - оноу станавливается.